# Ajax returns No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: python, ajax, bottle

I have build a web service on python bottle that returns a json response, and when I send a request to the service I receive this error:

**

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my_url. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

**

I know that I have to enable the cors on my web-service, so I have added the following decorator to enable the cors.

```
@hook('after_request')    
def cors(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        bottle.response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        bottle.response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        bottle.response.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type")

        # skip the function if it is not needed
        if bottle.request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

and I'm sure that the decorator is called before return the response, but unfortunately the service still returns the same error.

any help how to solve this issue, and why the core is not enabled?

Comment: What response headers do you observe your server returning?